# Get shared library name from handle

Tags: c++, linux, shared-libraries

I'm calling a library function that takes a parameter, loads an appropriate shared library and returns a handle to the so. The library calls calls `dlopen` to open a reference to the shared library. Is there a way I can get the name/path of the shared library from the handle returned?

Comment: Probably not. What would you do with it?

Comment: May be [Glibc extensions](https://linux.die.net/man/3/dlopen) (not described in Posix) can help you: dladdr and dlvsym

Comment: @n.m. I'm writing a test suite and I need to assert the library to be the expected library before running the tests.

Comment: @TioPepe Thanks I'll look into that.

Comment: You can get the set of libraries before  and after the call e.g. from /proc/$$/maps, but symbolic links and dependent libraries make this a not very attractive method. You can also try and dlsym a known symbol from the handle (e.g. _init) and  then find at what range it falls in the maps. Still won't solve the symlink issue.

Comment: @n.m. I got it working using the dlladdr. There's a common function in every shared library loaded. I used dlsym to get that function address and used dladdr() to get the file name. :)